# How to work with MySQL temp tables in a Galera Cluster?

Tags: mysql, database-replication, galera

I am scaling my application from one MySQL server to a 3 node MySQL Galera Gluster. Aparently temporary tables do not get replicated.

Is there a common workaround this problem?

My current code looks like this:

```
        $stmt = "
            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (`city_id` MEDIUMINT( 8 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,INDEX ( `city_id` ) )
        ";          
        db_query($stmt);
        # travel tips
        $stmt = "
            INSERT INTO tmp
            SELECT city_id
            FROM $DB.$T33 g
            WHERE g.country_code = '$country[code]'
            GROUP BY city_id
        ";          
        execute_stmt($stmt, $link);
```

The error message is:

> Error: 1146 Table 'test.tmp' doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` creates a table visible only to the session where it was created.  No other connections can see it.
- A single connection stays connected to one node.

With those two in mind, it does not matter whether such a table is replicated.

- `ROW` based replication is a requirement of Galera.
- `MyISAM` tables are not replicated.

With those two additional bullet items, it does not even matter if the `TEMPORARY TABLE` is `ENGINE=MyISAM` (or `MEMORY`).

Back to your problem.  What do `db_query` and `execute_stmt` do?

- Do they also connect to the server?  Not good.  Have only one connection for your program.
- Do they go through some form of Proxy before getting to a Galera node?  It would not be good for it to be switching nodes.